# How to select specific row if X, multiple rows if Y

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table Table(id,name), but lets just work with id here

```
id
--
A 
B 
C 
D 
all
```

What I want is to select all rows (A,B,C D...) except 'all' if the input is all, otherwise only the specific value ( e.g.: A if the input is A ).

Do you guys have some tasty-juicy solution for this one? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `select * frmo table1 where id = @x or @x is null`?

Comment: What error are you getting?  This is very basic SQL.

Comment: I don't get an error, I just need a little help for the full solution ( this is part of a problem I'm working on) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a parameter `@Id` in your query. Then you can formulate your `WHERE` clause based on `@Id`'s value:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE i.Id <> 'all' AND (@Id='all' OR @Id=t.Id)
```

`i.Id <> 'all'` part ensures that `'all'` row is never returned, regardless of the setting of `@Id`. The rest is your condition translated to SQL (i.e. either the query has `'all'`, or the query matches a single `Id`).

Comment: You have a good solution as well. The other guy was a bit faster, this is why i'm marking him as the answer. But thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the wrong usage of a relational table as the "id" column should contain only ids...

I suggest removing the "all" row and instead write a stored procedure to decide whether to select all rows or just one.

Anyway, for your example:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (id = @ID OR @ID = 'all') AND id <> 'all'
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what i was looking for exactly.

Comment: you are welcome, you can flag the answer as accepted ;)